Why I cannot map response to my response DTO?

I try to use plainToInstance function from class transformer but when i try to map field from repose to my DTO it can mapping but it incorrect in my DTO i have some field i want to response but when mapped finish it return all field

async createContainer(@Query('name') name:string): Promise<CreateContainerDto>  {
    console.log(name);
    
    try{
        const res = await this.imageService.createContainer(name)
        const dto = plainToInstance(CreateContainerDto,res)
        console.log(res);
        console.log(dto);
        return dto
    }


This is my service try to mapping response to DTO

import { IsDate, IsString } from "class-validator"

export class CreateContainerDto{
    @IsString()
    etag: string
    @IsString()
    requestId: string
    @IsDate()
    date: Date

}

I want response some field to user

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

plainToInstance function is deprecated use plainToClass instead, like below:
        const dto = plainToClass(
           CreateContainerDto,
           res,
           { excludeExtraneousValues: true }
         )

and in your dto expose the props you want to show.
import { IsDate, IsString, Expose } from "class-validator"

export class CreateContainerDto{
    @Expose()
    @IsString()
    etag: string

    @Expose()
    @IsString()
    requestId: string

    @Expose()
    @IsDate()
    date: Date
}

